# Jquery - draggable div and mousedown on parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, parent, mousedown

I have a draggable div (div#paper), children of another div (div.whitepaper). I want to drag the div#paper inside the div.whitepaper without limits.

So, I want to drag div#paper even if I'm not over div#paper, even if I mousedown to div.whitepaper.

This is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/klodenet/x85Uu/

If I drag div#paper over the space of div.whitepaper, and I continue to mousedown+mousemove into div.whitepaper, I want div#paper continue to drag overside...

I have added a .trigger() solution commented, because if I use this solution with Firebug, Firefox crashes.

Comment: I have add this variation: http://jsfiddle.net/klodenet/x85Uu/6/

Comment: I have assigned the id "paperSpace" to div.whitepaper, so I've used the method "bind" on div#paperSpace. then, I have used the method trigger for the event e. I get a solution, but the result gone too slowly. If I enable the firebug on firefox, I get a redundant action on line with trigger event... This is my new modify: http://jsfiddle.net/klodenet/x85Uu/9/

Comment: I have finally found my solution!!! In fact, if I use #paperSpace without any children element, I can trigger any event on it to the element #paper. So, when an event to #paper element, as a children of the element #paperSpace, is in action, the event is applied to the children element as on the parent element #paperSpace. Here we have a redundant execution of the trigger events. I wish this last solution can be explained as is: http://jsfiddle.net/klodenet/x85Uu/11/